# Futura leading: perceived line distance for numbers is off

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography

Here's a part of a potential business card, the problem lies in the distance of the middle line to the other two. It seems closer to the top which really bugs me.

What would a professional typographer do? Center it visually or does the consistency of the leading take priority and I shouldn't worry?

[image: sample image]

Answer (score 4):

The central source of visual disharmony you are facing here is that, roughly speaking, you have one line with normal capitalisation, one line in all caps and one line without any caps. It is comparable to the following:

> Lojem Ipsum
>   DOLOR SIT AMET
>   conseceur aduscun esot

This effect is emphasised by:

- Two descenders in the first line, in particular an early one in *Space*
- No ascenders whatsoever before the @ in the third line.

I would guess that your example would already look much better, if you write *first.second* instead of *name.surname* in your last line.

To go one step further:

- Use lowercase numbers in the third line (and use a more random example to distribute the descenders more evenly).
- Captialise the e-mail adress, i.e., *Name.Surname@Outlook.com.* If I am not mistaken, there is hardly any e-mail server that cares about capitalisation (when in doubt, check) and this helps the reader to identify the structure of the e-mail address.

Comment: Or instead of capitals in the email, make the @ a few points smaller until it matches the x-height of the lowercase letters.

Comment: Or consider breaking them out into 3 boxes and manually place the phone number box rather than relying on leading etc.

Answer (score 3):

A professional designer *always* worries about these types of details. :)

The simple answer: Adjust things until they look right to you.

Another option is to find a version of Futura that includes old-style numerals. Old-style numerals are designed to emulate the ascenders and descenders of type so you don't end up with this problem in the first place:

[image]

Comment: Coo. Aren't those numerals horrible?! They are quite the ugliest I've encountered, and I rather like the base fonts themselves.